# schwa and /æ/ in 'can you can a can as a canner can can a can'

Tags: tongue-twisters

Can somebody tell me when the sounds 'schwa' and /æ/ are used in the following tongue twister:

**Can you can a can as a canner can can a can**.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you?

Comment: When I pronounce the sentence all the "cans" sound the same to me.  Of course, they might sound different others, plus I might pronounce "can" differently in other contexts (or when I'm not observing myself).

Comment: They are all unreduced  /æ/ in that sentence. That's part of what makes it a tongue twister, although I think it must be one of the easiest tongue twisters around.

Comment: (Of course, I doubt that I could do the Can Can.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the modal "can" is optionally, and often, reduced from [kʰæn] to [kʰən] when it is not being emphasised.

Comment: So you are saying that "can" can rhyme with "bun"?

Comment: No, since "bun" is pronounced [bʌn] or, more likely, [bɐn] (at least in most dialects of English, though in mine it happens to be [bʊn]). It's like the reduction of "to" from [tʰuː] to [tʰə].

Comment: Unstressed "can" often rhymes with unstressed "been".  It's more like **c'n**.

Comment: Unstressed "can" doesn't rhyme with unstressed "been" in _most_ dialects since the former is pronounced [kʰən], the latter [bɪn] (though there might well be dialects where they do in fact rhyme).

Comment: Merriam Webster and several other dictionaries have ["bun" as \ˈbən\.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bun) But they also have "can" as \kən, ˈkan also ˈken; dialectal ˈkin\. So I am starting to think that the schwa is not one single sound anymore--only a representation for an unstressed vowel with several different pronunciations.

Comment: That is probably just their own in-house transcription system not matching the IPA. In General American (and America generally), "bun" is /bʌn/, stressed modal "can" is /kæn/, unstressed modal "can" is /kən/, stressed "been" is /biːn/ (or sometimes /bɛn/) and unstressed "been" is /bɪn/ (or sometimes /bɛn/, too).

Comment: There are definitely American dialects where unstressed *can* rhymes with unstressed *been*, and I think they are quite common. Many dialects that don't have the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_high_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger) reduce /æ/ to /ɪ/.

Comment: I see. In any case, this goes a bit off-topic from the OP's question.

Comment: Playing with it some more, I've observed that I *might* pronounce the first and fifth occurrences of the word as "kin", if I'm being "relaxed" and casual.

Comment: Yes, schwa. In New York and New Jersey area, we pronounce the **verb** with schwa rather than rhyming with man. That's the opening word and the one right after the noun *canner*. Not kin, but the opening to kinesiology.